# BigDecimal.doubleValue does not exist?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to find a simple way to round a double to two decimal places. I am using a BigDecimal to do the trick but noticed that the function [`doubleValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue--) of the java.math.BigDecimal class does not exist.

The following function:

```
fun Double.roundTo2DecimalPlaces() =
    BigDecimal(this).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()
```

Is giving me this compile error:

```
:compileKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
w: The '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-module' is specified
e: -{FilePathAndNameWereHere}-: (20, 14): Unresolved reference: doubleValue
:compileKotlin FAILED
```

Kotlin version is 1.1.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

can you not use `toDouble()` instead, ie:

```
fun Double.roundTo2DecimalPlaces() =
    BigDecimal(this).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toDouble()
```

Comment: Thanks! ;) You got it! Turns out I was using BigDecimal wrong as well. I updated my question so BigDecimal was used correctly. But left incorrectness of original question. You can edit your answer to reflect so people don't copy broken code.  The ```setScale``` function actually returns a new BigDecimal at the asked scale.   ```toDouble``` was the key! You're the boss.

Comment: What is your opinion on editing your answer to reflect the correct use of the method. As is that method will not round because d.setScale does not mutate the original object.

Comment: I did try to put an edit through but was rejected by the community: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17149135   Don't mind re-accepting this answer if I can get a good reason why not. Or more in my favor of my opinion, if the incorrect parts of the code not related to the question are changed.

Comment: @DaveThomas agreed. updated. (also, good eye on the previous mis-use `setScale`)

Comment: This is not applicable to Kotlin/JS

Answer (score 1):

I found this question looking how to replace Javascript `[toFixed(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)'

```
fun Double.toFixed(s : Int): Double {
    if (s==0) return round(this)
    val power = (10.0).pow(s)
    return round(this * power)/power
}
```

This method is x20 faster than converting to a `BigDecimal` but suffers from floating point inaccuracy in extreme examples.

```
Assert.assertEquals(4238764872.745398676, 4238764872.745398675983467.toFixed(9), 0.00000000001)
```

fails for the above, but succeeds for the accepted answer (changing the scale to a parameter)